# String to be escaped was not valid UTF-8 or could not be converted zend 2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, zend-framework2

Hello all I am creating form on zend 2.3 framework. And getting the following error message String to be escaped was not valid UTF-8 or could not be converted. In my editor zend studio that is I changed encoding to utf-8 before importing the project into a workspace. This is the stack tracce of this error:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Escaper\Escaper.php(162): Zend\Escaper\Escaper->toUtf8('?????????')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtmlAttr.php(25): Zend\Escaper\Escaper->escapeHtmlAttr('?????????')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper.php(51): Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtmlAttr->escape('?????????')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper.php(233): Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper->__invoke('?????????')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput.php(128): Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper->createAttributesString(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput.php(101): Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput->render(Object(Zend\Form\Element\Submit))
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput->__invoke(Object(Zend\Form\Element\Submit))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(399): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSubmit), Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\module\Admin\view\admin\admin\addstudent.phtml(36): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('formSubmit', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\module\Admin\view\admin\admin\addstudent.phtml(36): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->formSubmit(Object(Zend\Form\Element\Submit))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(506): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(103): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(352): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(327): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\disability\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

Here is the code of the form's view

```
<?php
 // module/Album/view/album/album/add.phtml:

 $title = 'add student';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

<div id="allarea">
<?php
// $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('Admin\Controller\AdminController', array('action' => 'Admin\Form\AddstudentForm')));
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('admin', array('action' => 'addstudent')));

 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('fio'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('gender'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('birthdate'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('edge'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('university'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('group'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('department'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('grate'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('enterence'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('financesource'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('studyform'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('homeaddress'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('actualaddress'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('phone'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('workplace'));


 echo $this->formRow($form->get('services'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>



</div>
```

here is the file Form/Addstudent.php

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class AddstudentForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('addstudent');


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'fio',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'fio',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'gender',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'gender',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'm',
                    '1' => 'f',
                ),

            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'birthdate',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'birthdate',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'edge',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'edge',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'university',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'vuz',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'group',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'gruoup',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'department',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'department',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'grate',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'greate',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => '1',
                    '1' => '2',
                    '2' => '3',
                    '3' => '4',
                    '4' => '5',
                    '5' => '6',

                ),

            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'enterence',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'enterance year',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'financesource',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'finance source',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'butget',
                    '1' => 'contract',

                ),

            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'studyform',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'studyform',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'on side',
                    '1' => 'distance',

                ),

            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'homeaddress',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Home address',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'actualaddress',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'actual address',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'phone',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'phone',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'workplace',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'workplace',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'services',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'services',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'save',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

this is the filter

```
<?php 
namespace admin\Model;

 // Add these import statements
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

 class Admin implements InputFilterAwareInterface
 {
     public $fio;
     public $gender;
     public $birthdate;
     public $edge;
     public $university;
     public $group;
     public $department;
     public $grate;
     public $enterence;
     public $financesource;
     public $studyform;
     public $homeaddress;
     public $actualaddress;
     public $phone;
     public $workplace;
     public $services;
     protected $inputFilter;                       // <-- Add this variable

     public function exchangeArray($data)
     {
         $this->fio = (isset($data['fio'])) ? $data['fio'] : null;
        // $this->title  = (isset($data['title']))  ? $data['title']  : null;
         $this->gender = (isset($data['gender'])) ? $data['gender'] : null;
         $this->birthdate = (isset($data['birthdate'])) ? $data['birthdate'] : null;
         $this->edge = (isset($data['edge'])) ? $data['edge'] : null;
         $this->university = (isset($data['university'])) ? $data['university'] : null;
         $this->group = (isset($data['group'])) ? $data['group'] : null;
         $this->department = (isset($data['department'])) ? $data['department'] : null;
         $this->grate = (isset($data['grate'])) ? $data['grate'] : null;
         $this->enterence = (isset($data['enterence'])) ? $data['enterence'] : null;
         $this->financesource = (isset($data['financesource'])) ? $data['financesource'] : null;
         $this->studyform = (isset($data['studyform'])) ? $data['studyform'] : null;
         $this->homeaddress = (isset($data['homeaddress'])) ? $data['homeaddress'] : null;
         $this->actualaddress = (isset($data['actualaddress'])) ? $data['actualaddress'] : null;
         $this->phone = (isset($data['phone'])) ? $data['phone'] : null;
         $this->workplace = (isset($data['workplace'])) ? $data['workplace'] : null;
         $this->services = (isset($data['services'])) ? $data['services'] : null;
         $escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8');
     }

     // Add content to these methods:
     public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
     {
         throw new \Exception("Not used");
     }

     public function getInputFilter()
     {
         if (!$this->inputFilter) {
             $inputFilter = new InputFilter();


             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'fio',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'birthdate',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'university',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'group',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'department',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'enterence',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'homeaddress',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'actualaddress',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'phone',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));
             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'workplace',
                 'required' => false,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));


             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'services',
                 'required' => false,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 2000,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

         }
             $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;

         return $this->inputFilter;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help you. Please edit your question to include at least the code for the submit button that is producing this error. More enough about how you get this error would be useful too - does it happen when you load the page with the form on? Only when you submit the form?

Comment: @ Tim Fountain Hello I just edited the question. The error is shown when page with form loads.

Comment: Code looks fine. If you remove the submit button temporarily does it work?

Comment: @TimFountain Sorry for scilence I removed the submit button and form rendered successfuly. Any ideas what it is?

Comment: Even if I change type of submit to button I am getting the same error.

Comment: This error can appear when you send `null` value to `Zend\Escaper`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem. The problem was in the controller. It is strange, but the controller file had cp1251 charset, despite the fact that I changed charset globaly in zend studio. So I changed the controller's encoding in its properties and now it is working properly.

Comment: Hey man I am having an identical problem to what you had. Will you please add the code that you had to change to fix this? I do not see anywhere in my program what you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your inputFilter method.

```
'validators' => [
['name' => 'NotEmpty'],

[
    'name'    => 'StringLength',
    'options' => [
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'min' => 1,
        'max' => 200,
    ],
],
],
```

Also, in your code, where you create a new instance to Zend\Escaper\Escaper add `'utf-8'` as a parameter to the constructor like that: `$escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8');`

If this doesn't work, show us your inputFilter code.

EDIT: I strongly recommend you to upgrade to zend 2.4.6 due to the huge amount of bug/security fixes. Just keep in mind that the Zend\Db component had some major changes in version 2.4 onward.

Comment: Interesting think I just var dumped the submit button variable and it said "string(62)" with empty value.